# main SELECT gets value from subquery

Tags: mysql

This query doesn't work but I hope it will suffice to make you understand what I need:

```
SELECT p.ID, lat.l 
FROM hlp_posts AS p
WHERE p.ID 
IN (SELECT pm.post_id, pm.meta_value AS l FROM hlp_postmeta AS pm WHERE pm.meta_key = "hlp_latitude") lat
```

What I need is getting in the main SELECT a value (`lat.l`) selected in the subquery.
I can get it through a JOIN but I can't use it.

Comment: if you use the `IN` you are bound to return a single column in the subquery, which is the one used to evaluate the condition, this way is going to be impossible to fetch `meta_value `. Any specific reason why you can't use the `JOIN`?

Comment: I know it seems strange but JOINS in this case are behaving very slow.  In the complete code I have like 15 JOINS. Since from a few tests subqueries are behaving better I am trying to refactor my code with them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `JOIN` instead, e.g.:

```
SELECT p.id, pm.meta_value
FROM hlp_posts AS p JOIN hlp_postmeta pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
WHERE pm.meta_key = "hlp_latitude";
```

Comment: Are there any performance reason to use joins since in is old and should be avoid my question is specific if join will faster my query

Comment: @Noob you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query) SO answer. I'd say it depends on index rather than join vs sub query.

Comment: Thanks this will help me since I want to proving my database skills specially on indexing.